# What does running only "gradle" execute?

Tags: gradle

if we executed "gradle" command only in terminal, the result is below.

```
$ gradle

> Task :help

Welcome to Gradle 4.10.

To run a build, run gradle <task> ...

To see a list of available tasks, run gradle tasks

To see a list of command-line options, run gradle --help

To see more detail about a task, run gradle help --task <task>

For troubleshooting, visit https://help.gradle.org

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 0s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

What is it? I wonder exactly what action was taken

Answer (score 0):

The `Task :help` is your clue. It's running the `help` task by default. To change it, see [Default Tasks](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#sec:default_tasks) in the Gradle documentation for some insight on how you can change the default task for a Gradle project.